# Calling AS400 DB from .Net Core

Tags: db2, .net-core

I have a .Net Core WebAPI, and I have the IBM.Data.DB2.Core package installed.
When I try to call the DB2Connection constructor with a connection string, I'm getting the following error.

> Unable to load DLL 'db2app64.dll': The specified module could not be found.

Is this something that should be included with the DB2.Core package? Is there a better way to call an AS400 DB from .Net Core?

My code looks like this:

```
DB2Connection conn = new DB2Connection("Server=as400.example.com;Database=CLIENTS01;UID=user1;PWD=password1;");
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are using the .NET Core package, you will have to include the path to the driver (which is included in the NuGet package) in your PATH variable.

Here's the relevant part of the [FAQ on the NuGet package on Developer Works](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/96960515-2ea1-4391-8170-b0515d08e4da/entry/Instructions_for_downloading_and_using_DB2_NET_Core_provider_package?lang=en):

> Q: Do I need to do any additional configuration for using this
>   configuration.
>
> ```
>  Yes,  On Windows :
>    if C:\Users\<USERNAME>\ is the NuGet package folder then
>    add to the path:  C:\Users\<USERNAME>\.nuget\packages\IBM.Data.DB2.Core\1.0.0.100\build\clidriver\bin
>
>  and On Linux:
>     append $HOME/.nuget/packages/IBM.Data.DB2.Core-lnx/1.0.0.100/build/clidriver/lib
>     to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH.
> ```

I've found the easiest way to get it set is to set the PATH variable in your project settings. Check out [this blog post](https://www.exceptionnotfound.net/working-with-environments-and-launch-settings-in-asp-net-core/) about some different ways you can do that.

In fact, [this other Developer Works page](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/96960515-2ea1-4391-8170-b0515d08e4da/entry/DB2DotnetCore?lang=en) says:

> Instructions for downloading and using the package
>
> The following are the prerequisites for using the package
>
> - **Any other IBM DB Drivers should not be present in the machine.**
> - Path/LD_LIBRARY_PATH needs to be updated to include the package driver path.

Comment: What do you set the variable name to on linux?  I am running this in a ubuntu docker container btw.

Answer (score 0):

you need to install the IBM Data Server Driver Package wich you can get over there

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24038920

it includes the dependencies you are missing

Comment: Will this work to install on my pc for localhost testing?

Comment: yeah tough you will need to ship the dll to the production env later on as well

Comment: This is incorrect. The .NET Core package specifically says that other driver packages are not needed. It is self-contained, but your application has to have the PATH variable set to the correct value for it to find the DLLs.

Comment: @bhamby is correct. The Nuget package has the driver included. If you compare the Nuget package contents to that of the driver install, they're almost the same. His answer should get you working. The downside to also installing the driver, along with the Nuget package, would be having 2 drivers installed, which may be differing versions etc.